# CI 3.1.3 URL in the address bar changed but showing the same page (default controller)

Tags: codeigniter

I got a problem here, I just created a website using CI 3.1.3, I already add a .htaccess file and also Setup the base_url config

`$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

I already create the Controller, and add it to the routes.
But whenever I click a link that redirect to another page, the url in the address bar is changed, the browser is loaded, but it still showing the same page that were set in the default controller, 
I already tried to search it on the google but can't find the answer, and actually I don't know how to describe my problem is.

But please help me to solve this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
$protocol = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$config['base_url'] = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Does it work without .htaccess and/or route config?

Comment: depending on your hosting request_uri might return different values.